# Xamarin Forms debugging on Android fails to start if app is already deployed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

At the moment my app is running on Xamarin Forms 3.1.0.583944. I have tried this both on a physical device and on an emulator and I get the same results. The first time I try to debug my app, it works pretty well. However if I launch it the second time, my screen turns white, and after a few seconds it just closes. My output only shows this:

> Android application is debugging.

That's it. No errors, no warnings, nothing. If I uninstall the app from my phone, and run it again it starts flawlessly. So it's not a critical issue but it does get annoying to manually remove my app everytime. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try to check your IDE logs in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\15.0

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/Z8xZfgKE) is the log from monodroid

Comment: It seems that it cannot find the NDK location, that can cause mismatched configurations in devices and emulators.

Comment: I installed NDK, added it to the xamarin options. Now it finds NDK but the issue remains

Comment: I've found [another log](https://pastebin.com/D2rMrx8h) where it shows deployment exceptions though